# Mexican version of WWV?

Tags: wwv

Does Mexico have a time transmitter like NIST's [WWV](https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/radio-stations/wwv) in the United States?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no radio stations that broadcast time and/or accurate frequencies in Mexico.

According to these webpages, here are no time or frequency stations *anywhere* in Central America.

- https://www.smeter.net/stations/hf-time-frequency.php
- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_clock#
- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_clock#List_of_radio_time_signal_stations

According to the last link above, there are some in South America if that helps you.